# How do I get a true/false result from PowerShell if the results match a string?

Tags: powershell

I am trying to get a true/false or 0/1 response based on a series of commands.  I might be approaching this wrong, but ultimately, I need to know if this exists.

```
PS > Get-VMNetworkAdapter -ManagementOS|Select -ExpandProperty SwitchName
LINK
Default Switch
```

I am looking to see if LINK exists then return true.  So in the case above, a command that will return true since LINK exists.

Comment: Something like `(Get-VMNetworkAdapter -ManagementOS).SwitchName -eq 'LINK'` you mean? or `(Get-VMNetworkAdapter -ManagementOS).SwitchName -contains 'LINK'` if the result is an array

Comment: You can save to a variable and evaluate again it if it's empty ($false), or not ($true). Also, you can just do `[bool](Get-VMNetworkAdapter -ManagementOS -ea 0 |Select -ExpandProperty SwitchName)`. Edit: ahhh, looking at this again after seeing Theo's comment, that's probably what you want.

Comment: Thanks!  Theo's second option was exactly what I Was going for.

Comment: @Theo definitely is the most elegant. Not having considered that wrapping the command by itself in parenthesis, and then referencing a property would give an array of that property, I had come up with `(Get-VMNetworkAdapter -ManagementOS | Where-Object SwitchName -eq "Link").Count -gt 0` It definitely works, but is not as elegant.

Comment: @Theo Post an answer :-)

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen Yes, you're right. Posted as answer now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the property `SwitchName` is a single item, you can use

```
(Get-VMNetworkAdapter -ManagementOS).SwitchName -eq 'LINK'
```

If that property contains an **array** of values as it appears to be, then I would go for

```
(Get-VMNetworkAdapter -ManagementOS).SwitchName -contains 'LINK'
```

The return value is a Boolean, either `$true` or `$false`

<sup>Both `-eq` and `-contains`  work Case-Insensitive. If you need Case-Sensitive, use `-ceq` or `-ccontains`</sup>